# How to return a dataframe value from row and column reference?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, scalar

I know this is probably a basic question, but somehow I can't find the answer. I was wondering how it's possible to return a value from a dataframe if I know the row and column to look for? E.g. If I have a dataframe with columns `1-4` and rows `A-D`, how would I return the value for `B4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) for this:

```
In [236]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4), index=list('ABCD'), columns=[1,2,3,4])
df

Out[236]:
          1         2         3         4
A  1.682851  0.889752 -0.406603 -0.627984
B  0.948240 -1.959154 -0.866491 -1.212045
C -0.970505  0.510938 -0.261347 -1.575971
D -0.847320 -0.050969 -0.388632 -1.033542

In [237]:
df.ix['B',4]

Out[237]:
-1.2120448782618383
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html), if rows are `A-D` and columns `1-4`:

```
print (df.at['B', 4])
```

If rows are `1-4` and columns `A-D`:

```
print (df.at[4, 'B'])
```

[Fast scalar value getting and setting](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#fast-scalar-value-getting-and-setting).

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,4),index=list('ABCD'), columns=[1,2,3,4])
print (df)
    1   2   3   4
A   0   1   2   3
B   4   5   6   7
C   8   9  10  11
D  12  13  14  15

print (df.at['B', 4])
7

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,4),index=[1,2,3,4], columns=list('ABCD'))
print (df)
    A   B   C   D
1   0   1   2   3
2   4   5   6   7
3   8   9  10  11
4  12  13  14  15

print (df.at[4, 'B'])
13
```